# Adding Alternative Text View In Exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I'm using the `ExchangeService` and the `EmailMessage` classes to send out emails.

Is there a way for me to add an alternative text view to the EmailMessage object? And if so, a code snippet showing how to do it would be great.

I know it was possible with the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could create your own EmailMessage object and derive from EmailMessage to add your own text view.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?